# Windows 11 and Android - BluetoothAdapter return null

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-android

I am trying to run Android app on win 11 with WSA - Windows Subsystem for Android.
My app using connection to bluetooth device (Not bluetooth audio device).
I am starting to scan for bluetooth devices and WSA is open bluetooth setting in windows settings window.
in logcat i can see this line:

```
BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
```

Is Windows Subsystem for Android supporting connection and communication with bluetooth device (Not Audio device)?
Thank you,
Salit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in Windows support this is the answer:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/3851

> Hi, currently in Windows Subsystem for Android bluetooth functionality such as scanning for BLE devices is not supported.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32023049)